# How can I get the Google cache age of any URL or web page?

Tags: html, url, hyperlink, web-scraping

In my project I need the Google cache age to be added as important information. I tried to search sources for the Google cache age, that is, the number of days since Google last re-indexed the page listed.

Where can I get the Google cache age?

Comment: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/15633/how-to-modify-a-url-to-get-a-google-cached-version-of-page

Answer (score 380, accepted):

Use the URL

```
https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:<your url without "http://">
```

Example:

> https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:stackoverflow.com

It contains a header like this:

> This is Google's cache of https://stackoverflow.com/. It is a snapshot of the page as it appeared on 21 Aug 2012 11:33:38 GMT. The current page could have changed in the meantime. Learn more
>   Tip: To quickly find your search term on this page, press **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>** or **<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>** (Mac) and use the find bar.

Comment: wow, it even works around `robots.txt`; I use it to read blogger since our corporate firewall disabled its URL

Comment: You can also use the `cache:` search operator in Google search

Comment: For `https` it requires the `https://` part, otherwise returns 404

Comment: This site does it this automatically: https://www.cachedview.me/

Comment: @lmaooooo please add that as a separate answer

Answer (score 18):

You'll need to scrape the resulting page, but you can view the most recent cache page using this [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator):

```
http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:www.something.com/path
```

Google information is put in the first div in the body tag.

Answer (score 15):

you can Use [CachedPages](http://www.cachedpages.com/) website

Cached pages are usually saved and stored by large companies with powerful web servers. Since such servers are usually very fast, a cached page can often be accessed faster than the live page itself:

- Google usually keeps a recent copy of the page (1 to 15 days old).
- Coral also keeps a recent copy, although it's usually not as recent as Google.
- Through Archive.org, you can access several copies of a web page saved throughout the years.

Answer (score 5):

its too simple, you can just type "cache:" before the URL of the page. for example
if you want to check the last webcache of this page simply type on URL bar `cache:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4560400/how-can-i-get-the-google-cache-age-of-any-url-or-web-page`

this will show you the last webcache of the page.see here:

[image]

But remember, the caching of a webpage will only show if the page is already indexed on search engine(Google). for this you need to check the meta robot tag of that page.

Comment: I used to use this for a long time. But it seems to fail on websites like medium.com recently.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this site: https://cachedviews.com/ . Cache View or Cached Pages of Any Website - Google Cached Pages of Any Website

Answer (score -1):

This one good also to view cachepage http://www.cachepage.net

1. Cache page view via google: webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache: Your url
2. Cache page view via archive.org: web.archive.org/web/*/Your url