# Recover Wordpress stylesheet

Tags: html, css, wordpress, content-management-system

I use Wordpress as a CMS and was working on a website and needed a little snippet of code from my own websites style sheet. Accidentally I saved other the WRONG stylesheet and have lost about a months work .. I know Wordpress.com blogs have the latest 25 revisions of there pages and stylesheets but does anyone know if I can retrieve them from my own sites when using Wordpress as a CMS? Any help would be really appreciated! I seriously don't want to lose all of Februarys work!

Thanks guys!

Comment: Have you tried Google? I'm pretty sure this is answered somewhere.

Comment: I'm having a browse now. Fingers crossed.

Comment: Maybe you can try to recover it with your browser cache? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4560400/how-can-i-get-the-google-cache-age-of-any-url-or-web-page

Comment: If you're using chrome, you can also try this: chrome://cache/ If you can find your file there, send me a message and I will show you how to recover it. It did the trick for me few weeks ago.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm using Safari. I HAVE however used Chrome to work with the specific style sheet in the last few days, just not in the instance I lost all my work @lefoy any suggestions?

Comment: I didn't try it, but maybe you can give this a try? http://dgc.uchicago.edu/20130906/recovering-a-file-from-safaris-cache/

Comment: @lefoy ok I have a recent version of the page up on chrome://cache/ I see a lot of computer language Im not familiar with though, lots of numbers ..

Comment: could you please upload a small screenshot of the page you have in your cache? Is it multiple lines like this? `00000010: e0 04 f7 a0 15 52 2e 00 c8 01 00 00 48 54 54 50  .....R......HTTP`

Comment: Thanks @lefoy I'll give that a go. What method did the trick for you exactly? Thats correct, lost of numbers, very similar to that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this online tool to recover you cached file : http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2012/01/viewing-chrome-cache-easy-way.html

Ref: [I recovered a file from chrome://cache, how do I read it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11531069/i-recovered-a-file-from-chrome-cache-how-do-i-read-it)

I hope that will help you :)

Comment: Thanks @lefoy its unfortunate I haven't restored all of my work but have managed to recover well over 80% of what was lost so I can happily take that as a win! Thanks so much, I really really appreciate it!