# How can I get the Google cache age of any URL or web page, Part II

Tags: caching, google-search

I'm trying to get a Google cache of a LinkedIn page.

I've seen several threads (e.g.: [How can I get the Google cache age of any URL or web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4560400/how-can-i-get-the-google-cache-age-of-any-url-or-web-page)) saying you can just append "http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:" to the URL, and that seems to work for pages where Google is already displaying links to the cached version.

But the drop-down link has been deactivated for several pages I'm trying to access. And in those cases, the above solution just gets me 404'd.

Any ideas how to get around this?